# How to render html in SWIG view express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

I have a html code data in mysql column, then i call it on the view (using swig view module). How to display it pretty like a html code in view?

**server.js**

```
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

**controller.js**

```
  newsExports.insertNews(title, content, dateadded, validpercent, basetitle, function(news){
    res.render('index/news', {news: news});
  })
```

**view.html**

```
 {% for i in news %}
  {{i.content}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer:
http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/

use the `{{i.content|safe}}`
or `{%raw%} {{i.content}}{%endraw%}`

its works like a charm!